# How to get values of multi select input with auto complete in controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui-autocomplete, multi-select

I'm using following code for multiselect

```
<input id="myAutocomplete" name="teaches[]" type="text" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
  <?php foreach ($classes_subject as $class_subject) : ?> "<?php echo $class_subject['class_subject'] . '   of ' . $class_subject['class'] ?>",
  <?php endforeach; ?>
    ];
  $('#myAutocomplete').autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  multiselect: true
    });
  })
</script>
```

when I am printing this array `teaches[]` in controller, it is showing empty. I'm including autocomplete plugin and it is working fine but when i try to print `teaches[]` it shows nothing. And my controller code is

```
public function insert_tutor(){  
  $teaches = $data['teaches'];
  print_r($teaches ); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use autocomplete plugin before. But according to [this demo](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/multiple.html),

Set `name` attribute to `teaches` (not an array)

```
<input id="myAutocomplete" name="teaches" type="text" />
```

Then you can

```
$teaches = $this->input->post("teaches");
$array = explode(",",$teaches);
print_r($array);
```